# How to insert multiple data before close tag in xml file?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I want to generate `sitemap.xml` via PHP with `DOMDocument`

Now I have three array:

```php
$category[] = array(
    'loc' => 'http://example.com/?=10',
    'lastmod' => '2019-05-12 10:47:05',
    'changefreq' => 'always', 
    'priority' => '1.0'
);
$board[] = array(
    'loc' => 'http://example.com/?=3',
    'lastmod' => '2019-05-12 10:47:05',
    'changefreq' => 'always', 
    'priority' => '1.0'
);
$article[] = array(
    'loc' => 'http://example.com/?='.$row['id'],
    'lastmod' => $row['last_mod'],
    'changefreq' => $row['changefreq'],
    'priority' => $row['priority']
);
```

The options:

```php
//Set Sitemap
$seoOption = array(
    'version' => '1.0',
    'charset' => 'UTF-8',
    'xml_filename' => 'seo.xml'
);
$seo = new SitemapGenerator($seoOption);
$seo->generateXML($category);
$seo->generateXML($board);
$seo->generateXML($article);
```

And this is my function:

```php
<?php
class SitemapGenerator
{
    public static $document = null;
    private static $options = array();

    public function __construct($option = array())
    {
        if (isset($option)) {
            self::$options = $option;
            //Initialize DOMDocument class
            if (!self::$document) {
                self::$document = new DOMDocument(self::$options['version'], self::$options['charset']);
                self::$document->formatOutput = true;
                self::$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            }
        } else {
            return 'Could not find option';
        }
    }


    public function generateXML($result)
    {
        $xml = $this->createElement('urlset');
        //Set the attributes.
        $xml->setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
        $this->appendChild($xml);
        foreach ($result as $var) {
            $var['lastmod'] = $this->trimLastmod($var['lastmod']);
            $item = $this->createElement('url');
            $xml->appendChild($item);
            $this->createItem($item, $var);
        }
    }

    public function finishGenerateXML()
    {
        $this->saveFile(self::$options['xml_filename']);
        $this->saveXML();
    }

    private function trimLastmod($value)
    {
        return date('c', strtotime($value));
    }

    //Create element
    private function createElement($element)
    {
        return self::$document->createElement($element);
    }

    //Append child node
    private function appendChild($child)
    {
        return self::$document->appendChild($child);
    }

    //Add item
    private function createItem($item, $data, $attribute = array())
    {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
                //Create an element, the element name cannot begin with a number
                is_numeric($key{0}) && exit($key.' Error: First char cannot be a number');
                $temp = self::$document->createElement($key);
                $item->appendChild($temp);
                //Add element value
                $text = self::$document->createTextNode($val);
                $temp->appendChild($text);
                if (isset($attribute[$key])) {
                    foreach ($attribute[$key] as $akey => $row) {
                        //Create attribute node
                        $temps = self::$document->createAttribute($akey);
                        $temp->appendChild($temps);
                        //Create attribute value node
                        $aval = self::$document->createTextNode($row);
                        $temps->appendChild($aval);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    //Return xml string
    private function saveXML()
    {
        return self::$document->saveXML();
    }

    //Save xml file to path
    private function saveFile($fpath)
    {
        //Write file
        $writeXML = file_put_contents($fpath, self::$document->saveXML());
        if ($writeXML === true) {
            return self::$document->saveXML();
        } else {
            return 'Could not write into file';
        }
    }

    //Load xml file
    public function loadSitemap($fpath)
    {
        if (!file_exists($fpath)) {
            exit($fpath.' is a invalid file');
        }
        //Returns TRUE on success, or FALSE on failure
        self::$document->load($fpath);
        return print self::$document->saveXML();
    }
}
```

Which result I want to get:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/?=10</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-05-12T10:47:05+08:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/?=3</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-05-12T10:47:05+08:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>1</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-05-22T10:47:05+08:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>2</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-05-22T10:47:05+08:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

And the actual result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/?=10</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-05-12T10:47:05+08:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/?=3</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-05-12T10:47:05+08:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>1</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-05-22T10:47:05+08:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>2</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-05-22T10:47:05+08:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

It generate duplicate `<urlset>` tags..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify the `generateXML` method and move the pieces of code that create the urlset to a new method you can then call `generateXML` many times without generating the `urlset` repeatedly. Below the `__construct`, `generateXML` were modified and a new method `addurlset` added...

```
<?php

    class SitemapGenerator{
        public static $document = null;
        private static $options = array();

        public function __construct( $option = array() ){
            if( isset( $option ) ) {
                self::$options = $option;

                if (!self::$document) {
                    self::$document = new DOMDocument(self::$options['version'], self::$options['charset']);
                    self::$document->formatOutput = true;
                    self::$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

                    /* generate the urlset once */
                    $this->addurlset();
                }
            } else {
                return 'Could not find option';
            }
        }

        /* generate the root node - urlset */
        private function addurlset(){
            $urlset=$this->createElement( 'urlset' );
            $urlset->setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
            $this->appendChild( $urlset );
        }

        /* add item to xml */
        public function generateXML( $result=array() ){
            if( !empty( $result ) && is_array( $result ) ){

                $urlset=self::$document->getElementsByTagName('urlset')[0];

                foreach ($result as $var) {
                    $var['lastmod'] = $this->trimLastmod($var['lastmod']);
                    $item = $this->createElement('url');
                    $urlset->appendChild($item);
                    $this->createItem($item, $var);
                }
            }
        }









        public function finishGenerateXML()
        {
            $this->saveFile(self::$options['xml_filename']);
            $this->saveXML();
        }
        private function trimLastmod($value)
        {
            return date('c', strtotime($value));
        }
        //Create element
        private function createElement($element)
        {
            return self::$document->createElement($element);
        }
        //Append child node
        private function appendChild($child)
        {
            return self::$document->appendChild($child);
        }
        //Add item
        private function createItem($item, $data, $attribute = array())
        {
            if (is_array($data)) {
                foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
                    //Create an element, the element name cannot begin with a number
                    is_numeric($key{0}) && exit($key.' Error: First char cannot be a number');
                    $temp = self::$document->createElement($key);
                    $item->appendChild($temp);
                    //Add element value
                    $text = self::$document->createTextNode($val);
                    $temp->appendChild($text);
                    if (isset($attribute[$key])) {
                        foreach ($attribute[$key] as $akey => $row) {
                            //Create attribute node
                            $temps = self::$document->createAttribute($akey);
                            $temp->appendChild($temps);
                            //Create attribute value node
                            $aval = self::$document->createTextNode($row);
                            $temps->appendChild($aval);
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        //Return xml string
        private function saveXML()
        {
            return self::$document->saveXML();
        }
        //Save xml file to path
        private function saveFile($fpath)
        {
            //Write file
            $writeXML = file_put_contents($fpath, self::$document->saveXML());
            if ($writeXML === true) {
                return self::$document->saveXML();
            } else {
                return 'Could not write into file';
            }
        }

        //Load xml file
        public function loadSitemap($fpath)
        {
            if (!file_exists($fpath)) {
                exit($fpath.' is a invalid file');
            }
            //Returns TRUE on success, or FALSE on failure
            self::$document->load($fpath);
            return print self::$document->saveXML();
        }
    }//end class





    $category[] = array(
        'loc' => 'http://example.com/?=10',
        'lastmod' => '2019-05-12 10:47:05',
        'changefreq' => 'always', 
        'priority' => '1.0'
    );
    $board[] = array(
        'loc' => 'http://example.com/?=3',
        'lastmod' => '2019-05-12 10:47:05',
        'changefreq' => 'always', 
        'priority' => '1.0'
    );
    $article[] = array(
        'loc' => 'http://example.com/?=404',
        'lastmod' => '2019-05-13 10:47:05',
        'changefreq' => 'weekly',
        'priority' => '0.5'
    );


    $seoOption = array(
        'version'       => '1.0',
        'charset'       => 'UTF-8',
        'xml_filename'  => 'seo.xml'
    );
    $seo = new SitemapGenerator($seoOption);
    $seo->generateXML($category);
    $seo->generateXML($board);
    $seo->generateXML($article);
    $seo->finishGenerateXML();
?>
```